# Uploading a filename to mysql database

Tags: php, mysql, sql, upload

I am trying to upload a file name selected through a form with a 'browse' button on the previous page. The code to do this:

```
$filename = $_FILES['userfile']['name']; // Get the name of the file (including file extension).

//inserting data order
$clip = "INSERT INTO musicdb
            (clipID, clipName, genre)
            VALUES
            ('','$filename','$name1')";
```

This works fine when trying to upload a file with no apostrophes in, however when trying to upload a file with an apostrophe **e.g "friends' birthday"** then it fails to upload to the mysql table. I think it's to do with the usage of " and ' interchangeably in the INSERT statement. I don't know which brackets `$filename = $_FILES['userfile']['name']` uses by default whether its " or '.

Thanks in advance

Comment: Echo the resulting `$clip` query and you will see the problem. Quotes (apostrophes) must be escaped.

Answer (score 0):

you need to escape your strings.

```
$filename = mysqli_real_escape_string($con, $filename);
```

Comment: This results in $filename being empty?

Answer (score 0):

Make sure to escape any variables you are using in a SQL statement.  For reference:

http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli.real-escape-string.php

Answer (score 0):

for the quotes use this for example

```
addslashes($str);
```

Comment: when you add slashes you will also have strip slashes. if i remember correctly.

Comment: exactly you need when you want to display the $str to use it

Answer (score 0):

First Replace apostrophes with another character(which not used in generally) From Requested file Name.
Then Insert into MySQL table.